# How to get 2 different page numberings in the same document in MS Word?

Tags: formatting, software, tools, pages, numerals

Let's say I have a 6 page document. (MS Word)

I want the first 3 pages to be numbered i, ii, iii
and the remaining 3 pages to be numbered 1, 2, 3

**How can I achieve this?**

I tried the automatic numbering option from office, but I can only have 1 numbering style. And I don't want to do it manually, because my document has so many pages that it will be very time consuming.

Comment: If you're referring to Word, you need to insert a Section Start on your fourth page (where you want it to start 1,2,3).

Comment: sorry, just edited my question. Yes i was referring to Word. Can you please explain how do i do that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=microsoft+word+insert+section+break&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgiLONhfvLAhUEn4MKHezmAwoQvwUIGigA&biw=1857&bih=942

Comment: Next you might consider asking questions like this on Super User, where it's more solidly on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't done this lately and I don't have Word on this machine, so this
may not be 100% accurate, but:

Insert a section break (new page) at the point where the numbering
should change. Go into headers/footers. Insert a field for page numbers
where you want it in the first section, formatted as Roman numerals. Go
to the next section (there's a button somewhere to do that). Turn off
the thing that says same header/footer as previous section. Insert page
numbers in this section, formatted as Arabic numerals.

Specific interface details will depend on what version of Word you have.
Look around in Word; use Google if you can't find something.